# Problem with maketitle and siunitx in journal template

Tags: titles, siunitx, tabu, journal-publishing, journal

I am using [this journal template](https://academic.oup.com/DocumentLibrary/GJI/gji-latex.zip) and have a problem when doing `\maketitle` after loading the siunitx package.

```
\documentclass[extra,mreferee]{gji}
\bibliographystyle{gji}

\let\tablenum\relax    
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\title{Some Fancy Research}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I get an error with this log:

```
! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.
<to be read again> 
               \cr 
l.10 \maketitle

There should be exactly one # between &'s, when an
\halign or \valign is being set up. In this case you had
none, so I've put one in; maybe that will work.
```

Without loading siunitx everything works fine. How might I be able to fix this?

EDIT: I just found out that this error is also caused by the tabu package. Not sure how this can help me though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue isn't `siunitx` or `tabu`, it's the standard `array` package (part of the core LaTeX distribution): `siunitx` loads `array`. That counts more or less as 'fundamentally defective' in terms of the behaviour of the class. You'll have to use is 'as is' (load no other packages) if that is what is required to submit to this journal.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping I could use these packages but looks like I will have to make do without them then..

Answer (score 5):

If you really must ypu can re-instate the original tabular just for the `\maketitle` settings.

```
\documentclass[extra,mreferee]{gji}

\makeatletter
\let\zz@tabular\@tabular
\let\zzendtabular\endtabular
\let\zz@xtabularcr\@xtabularcr
\let\zz@tabclassz\@tabclassz
\let\zz@tabclassiv \@tabclassiv 
\let\zz@tabarray\@tabarray
\makeatother

\bibliographystyle{gji}

\let\tablenum\relax    
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\title{Some Fancy Research}

{\makeatletter
\let\@tabular\zz@tabular
\let\endtabular\zzendtabular
\let\@xtabularcr\zz@xtabularcr
\let\@tabclassz\zz@tabclassz
\let\@tabclassiv \zz@tabclassiv 
\let\@tabarray\zz@tabarray
\maketitle
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, great advice! Would the same be possible for siunitx?

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented patch in the [latest GJI template](https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-geophysical-journal-international-gjiras/zjhxtdhcnprg).

The following minimal example works:

```
\documentclass[extra]{gji}
\let\tablenum\relax
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gji-siunitx-patch}

\title{Minimal working example with siunitx}
\author[J. Doe]
  {J. Doe$^1$ \\
  \affil{$^1$ Antarctica University, Antarctica}
  }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\SI{10}{\kilo\metre\per\second}
\end{document}
```

Note that one has to use the `\affil` command in order to retain the formatting.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!